# l’histoire positive

Tags: expressions, histoire

In the book *L'empire des steppes* by Rene Grousset, in the preface, it says:

> Leur
> arrivée, leurs mobiles, leur disparition semblent inexplicables, si bien que
> **l’histoire positive** n’est pas loin de faire sien le jugement des anciens auteurs
> qui voyaient en eux les fléaux de Dieu, envoyés pour le châtiment des vieilles
> civilisations.

Why is **histoire positive** translated into **historians of today**?

Comment: I wouldn't translate it "historians of today" as opposed to  "historians in the past" ;  I think (maybe I am wrong) it refers to the positiv**ist** movement  of the XIXth century (like Michelet). See here https://www.amazon.com/Lhistoire-Historiens-Critique-Consid%C3%A9r%C3%A9e-Positive/dp/1274718244

Comment: in English, see this link: Modern Era 
It was really not until the 19th Century that the idea of **presenting objective historical facts** became prevalent. Translation: objective  historical facts. https://www.philosophybasics.com/branch_philosophy_of_history.html The translation is wrong. [It is also not positivist.]

Comment: I agree with @JeanMarieBecker, *histoire positive* probably refers to historical positivism initiated in France at the end of the 19th century around Gabriel Monod (see  *[L'histoire dite « positiviste » en France](https://www.persee.fr/doc/roman_0048-8593_1978_num_8_21_5216)*). In 1939, when the book was published this line of thought was probably that of the then contemporary historians (you could ask the question on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: [continued] I have looked at the 1952 translation by Naomi Watford (a historian too) it says: "so much so that historians today come near to adopting the verdict of the writers of old,"  "historians today" fits with  "writers of old". Why she chose not to translate *histoire positive* but transfer the idea is not for me to explain, to save having to write a footnote? (it would have needed an explanation, that's for sure).

Comment: It seems that the literal context of the phrase is that modern historians generally tend to see past events in more positive light than more critical old historians... yet in this case they come to nearly same conclusions. Today we say this a lot: "positive thinking", "positive psychology", "positive parenting" (aussi en français).

Comment: @None Unless the history people on that site know French, whats the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voici un article d'un historien français qui traite ce thème:

> **Histoire positive contre histoire positiviste ?**
> Au substantif
> *positivisme* correspondent deux adjectifs, *positif* et *positiviste* qui
> recouvrent des acceptions différentes. Positiviste, nous dit Littré —
> dont on conviendra qu'il était mieux placé que quiconque pour en dire
> la signification — , désigne ce « qui L Histoire dite positiviste en
> France 185 se rapporte au positivisme, à la philosophie positive » ;
> sous sa forme substantive, ajoute-t-il, un positiviste est celui qui
> est « partisan de cette philosophie ».
> *Positif* a plusieurs sens.
> Retenons le second, toujours dans le Dictionnaire de la langue
> -française : « *positif*, qui s'appuie sur les faits, sur l'expérience, sur les notions a posteriori par rapport à ce qui s'appuie sur des
> idée a priori ».
>
> Prudence, amour du concret — du fait —, crainte de la nonobjectivité
> caractérisent l'esprit positif. Une vision du monde optimiste,
> progressiste, scientiste, articulée sur la loi des trois états, la
> hiérarchie dialectique des sciences, la recherche de l'efficacité,
> sous-tend l'esprit positiviste. Dès lors il apparaît que les
> historiens dits positivistes sont des historiens positifs.

**Carbonell Charles-Olivier. L'histoire dite « positiviste » en France.**

[l'article en entier](https://www.persee.fr/doc/roman_0048-8593_1978_num_8_21_5216)

Et cette définition du TLFi:

3. PHILOSOPHIE

> a) [En parlant de la connaissance ou d'un système de connaissances; p.oppos. *à théorique, rationnel, philosophique, métaphysique*] Qui
> repose sur des faits constatés ou vérifiables. *Connaissances
> positives; principes positifs; chimie positive; psychologie positive.
> Il n'y a donc réellement pour l'homme de vérités positives,
> c'est-à-dire, sur lesquelles il puisse solidement compter, que les
> faits qu'il peut observer, et non les conséquences qu'il en tire; que
> l'existence de la nature qui lui présente ces faits, ainsi que les
> matériaux pour en obtenir* (Lamarck, Philos. zool.,t.1, 1809, p.xxii):

> 3. De même que l'on oppose l'histoire **positive** [positive historical fact] à la philosophie de l'histoire, **en entendant par histoire positive l'ensemble des faits
>    historiques bien constatés, que chacun peut vérifier d'après les
>    sources, et dont la certitude est indépendante de l'opinion qu'on peut
>    se faire des conceptions philosophiques destinées à relier ces faits
>    entre eux** [positive historical fact]; de même on doit
>    entendre par science positive, ou par la partie **positive** des sciences,
>    la collection des faits que chacun peut vérifier, de manière à
>    acquérir la certitude qu'ils sont exacts, par un de ces procédés qui
>    ne laissent aucun doute dans l'esprit... Cournot, Fond.
>    connaiss.,1851, p.481.

[definition de positive](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/positive)

[C'est moi qui a mis les lettres en gras avant les crochets avec un terme en anglais]